# Authentication to host '192.168.0.31' for user 'username' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Unknown database 'mysql57'

Tags: c#, mysql, database

**Here is the error message:**

```
Unhandled exception. MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Authentication to host '192.168.0.31' for user 'username' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Unknown database 'mysql57'
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown database 'mysql57'
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.AuthenticationFailed(Exception ex)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate(Boolean reset)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate(String authMethod, Boolean reset)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
```

**I already tested numerous solutions but none of them worked.**

[**The database actually exists**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGqFN.png)

**You can download source project [Here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/zvo8czd9d2hpqyf/project-mysqlerror-database.zip/file).**

Answer (score 1):

The name of database is wrong. Check whether it is another name or case.

Comment: thanks for the help, but the database already exists

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot does not show that a database named `mysql57` actually exists. The error message is correct: the database name you're trying to use is wrong.

Try changing to `Database = brawldatabase;` in your connection string.

Answer (score -1):

**So I tried to fix the error myself but there is another one**

```
 Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'root' using method 'caching_sha2_password' failed with message: Unknown database 'mysql80'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).